# Sticky bottom bar iOS with scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, sticky-footer

I was going through this Medium iOS app when I stumbled upon [this amazing sticky bottom bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sm0lFRAe8Y)

See bottom bar. After the first content is finished and before the next content starts, the bottom bar starts moving

I tried it with using constraints and setting different priorities and their permutations and combinations but could not figure it out.

I also went through a [library](https://github.com/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout) which does something like that.

Can someone explain me how to go about making this kind of bottom bar?

Comment: you can use `viewForFooterInSection` table delegate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with the default behaviour of the `UITableView` Header/Footer depending on where you want the view.

Supply that view with its content to `UITableView` by it's delegate method `viewForHeaderInSection` or `viewForFooterInSection` and make sure your set the height correctly by the delegate methods `heightForHeaderInSection` and `heightForFooterInSection`.

That will give you a "bar" that moves in with it's content and out of view after it's related content is scrolled away.

Comment: let me check once.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it is working. Just wondering how did I miss footers in UITableView. I worked with them already.

Comment: No problem just be careful with the indexPath once you start using multiple sections.

Comment: Any idea, how to hide that line above the footer, when it starts scrolling?

Comment: I am not sure what line you are talking about but there might be two possible causes: 1. Line Separator, tableViews come with line separator between each cell, set it to none. 2. The height of the view you provided for the footer is lesser than the value you set in heightForFooterInSection. Therefore a blank area appeared between the footer and the last cell.

Comment: The footer that can be seen in the video (with a heart button), has a top border, that hides when the footer starts scrolling..

Comment: Maybe it is just me but it seemed to look the same to me scrolling or not, if it really bothers you maybe you want to screen cap and highlight the border you are seeing so I might know what is causing it?

Comment: Have a look now. I have added an annotation. Try to view it in high-resolution

Comment: I see, however I apologise for not being able to help. I have yet to encounter such a problem before as my header/footer have always been of a different colour. I will look into it when I can and see if I can find the cause of it.

Comment: It is more of a desired feature rather than a problem. I want to implement it.

Comment: Best I can think of now is to set the border of layer of the view for footer. Using view.layer.borderWidth and view.layer.borderColor where view is the view you provide for the footer, but that will create a border in all four sides of the view, not just between the footer and the content. You can call that in the UIScrollViewDelegate method - scrollViewDidScroll, scrollViewDidEndDragging and scrollViewDidEndDelecerating of your tableView. But I recommend you to ask another question to get a proper implementation.